# .htaccess RewriteRule rewriting my css, js and images files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change url from http://localhost/test/page1.html to  http://localhost/test/page1/ and i need to have trailing slash on the end of url.

this works with following .htacess rules

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

it also changes my paths to css, js...

from localhost/test/css/custom.css to 
localhost/test/page1/css/custom.css

I would like to have an idea how remove /page1/ folder from css path

Answer (score 2):

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/test/page1.html`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/test/page1/` the base suddenly becomes `/test/page1/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thank you for sugestion, i canot touch html pages. I hoping that is possible to exlude  folder /page1/ folder from css path via .htacess rules

Comment: Not sure  the solution is good for SEO , but you could try  `RewriteRule ^test/page[0-9]+/(.+\.(css|js))$ /test/$1 [NC,L,R]`  This will help remove the `/page123..`  from your css and js files.